# I faced a similar issue and fixed it by adding a BOOT_COMPLETED receiver to my app

Tags: android

I am working on pushnotification for android using FCM ,but my pushnotifications not working with device like MI,Oppo I have used following ;

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {

            Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, FBTokenService.class);
            context.startService(startServiceIntent);

            Intent notificationServiceIntent = new Intent(context, FBNotificationService.class);
            context.startService(notificationServiceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

this receiver is not at all called , can any one help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some manufacturers like MI, OPPO, Huawei have blocked apps to receive the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` action by default even if you have register in the manifest.

**Unless the user manually enable it by adding the "allow to launch at boot"(something like that) permission to the particular app in the Security Settings**, then you can get that action on boot complete.